# How to set up logwatch for OS X Server

Tags: mac-osx-server, logwatch

Logwatch is easy enough to install via Macports, and it seems to work but the amount of output it gives leaves something to be desired.  For example, this server is primarily a Samba file server, but logwatch prints out nothing concerning Samba.  What I do get is info concerning clamav, any security notifications in the system.log, & a printout of `df`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to configure it accordingly in `/opt/local/share/logwatch/default.conf/logfiles/samba.conf`. Adding the full path to the samba log (`/var/log/samba/log.smbd` and `log.nmbd`) files should be a first step.

Comment: Ok I changed samba.conf to specify the full path to log.smbd, then ran `sudo logwatch` & still nothing about samba.  Did I miss a step?